# How to extract values from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am doing one media player in java,
there I need to extract values from the string "01:23:02" as int x=01,y=23,z=02
for seek operation..

Comment: Note that its impossible to get 01 02 ints, do you want x="1" y="23" z="2" ints or strings  x="1" y="23" z="2"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it since you want `int` values:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("01:23:02").useDelimiter(":");
int x = scanner.nextInt();
int y = scanner.nextInt();
int z = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: he also asked for 01/02, you are right about 01 being impossible for an int, I had a brain fart.

Answer (score -1):

This is using C#

```
        string time = "01:23:02";
        string[] str = time.Split(':');
        int x = Convert.ToInt16(str[0]);
        int y = Convert.ToInt16(str[1]);
        int z = Convert.ToInt16(str[2]);
```